# windows10 pinging to windows7 pc but reverse says "timed out"

Tags: networking, ping

In our lab a windows10 desktop connected with a windows7 desktop through peer to peer Lan cable (cross link). windows10 can ping to windows7 whereas the reverse ping says "timed out". Someone please help. I tried firewall resetting to defaults but didn't solve.

Comment: instead of reseting the firewall, just try turn off the firewall

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I recommend the following methods:

1. First ping 127.0.0.1 on win7 computer, check if you can ping successfully, if it is not ok, you need reset TCP/IP protocol.
2. Check if the network rule has blocked the ICMP ping packets, I suggest you create an ICMP Inbound Rule. Specific links are as follows: [Create an Inbound ICMP Rule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-icmp-rule), then try to ping.
3. If none of the above two methods are successful, try to check if the firewall is turned off on win10 computer, then try to ping.
4. If none of the above three methods are successful, I recommend that you use the grab kit to see if you're dropping the bag, [Grab Kit Tools link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=4865). please feel free to contact me.

I hope my answer will be helpful to you.